# ESXi 6: Grant SSH access to non-administrator user account

Tags: vmware-esxi

For technical reasons that I won't go into, I need to grant SSH access to an extremely restricted (maintenance-only), non-administrator user account in VMware ESXi 6.

However, according to multiple sources, it seems that the only way to do this is to grant administrator permissions to the user account, either via the GUIs or via `/etc/security/access.conf`, which, obviously, I'm trying to avoid.

Is this the case? Do I have no other option?

Comment: There's got to be a better way of doing whatever it is you want to do than using SSH access, happy to help you if you can let us know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Chopper3 We have a single UPS, a single physical server, and two virtual servers so we need to implement graceful shut down of all VMs and the host on power loss. Everything I've read says that you need to use a single VM, pass through the USB device, install the software, and configure the software to call a script which, in turn, connects SSH and executes `/sbin/shutdown.sh && /sbin/poweroff` on the ESXi host. However, the credentials must be stored in plaintext, hence the attempt to use a restricted, non-administrator user account to do so.

Comment: Why not just spin up a very small (1 vcpu, minimal RAM, etc.) VM dedicated to monitoring the UPS?  You can then severely restrict access to this VM (no SSH, only specific admin users can use the console, etc.) and not worry about plaintext credentials being stored in a file.  Or just use ssh keys to authenticate to ESXi.

Comment: @BrandonXavier I considered that but our RMM system is expensive and charged per-instance so we want to setup the system on a VM that is already monitored otherwise something could go wrong with the dedicated VM, we wouldn't know, and it'd be too late when there's a power problem.

Comment: Most UPS's have an ESXi-specific module that will handle this for you without the fragile build-your-own method you're suggesting - certainly APC do.

Comment: @Chopper3 I seriously doubt it in this scenario. It's a really cheap, non-APC UPS and the documentation doesn't even cover self-tests, nevermind ESXi-specific operations. Anyway, best of a bad situation so my initial question still stands.

Comment: Ah, I see, fair enough I guess

Answer (score 1):

If the connection only needs to run the same list of commands on the ESXi host, one option to consider is using **SSH forced commands**. This feature allows you to force certain SSH keys to only run a given command on login.

This is handled through the **authorized_keys** file. On ESXi, it uses `/etc/ssh/keys-root/authorized_keys` for root logins and has this format:

```
command="/usr/local/bin/your_script.sh" <SSH_PUB_KEY>
```

You can also lock it down to a specific IP:

```
from="10.10.10.1",command="/usr/local/bin/your_script.sh" <SSH_PUB_KEY>
```

A bit late to the party for this answer, but hopefully this helps somebody on the interwebs!